# Can't get HDR's to work on my Mac

Tags: osx

Hello I am really new to blender (just started a few months ago) and I can't get any of my HDR skies to work, at first I thought it was because my mac automatically unzipped my files but after turning that off, my zip files won't show up in blender.

Comment: Did you pack your files? If the images are just replaced by a hot pink color, this is almost certainly the problem

Comment: sorry I am really new to this what does packing your file mean? And how would I go about doing it

Comment: After trying a million things I finally figured out the problem, the HDR wouldn't show up in the render view but after I  turned the samples to 100 it worked!

Comment: Sorry for the slow response, Chick. Packing your files is when you command blender to save your files with the .blend file. I find it very useful and enable it automatically through File> extra files > Pack all into .blend. You could also do this individually for each image. Also, long comment, by to unpack an image, shift-click the X next to the file name in the image select box.